# Is $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] secure?

Tags: php, api, http, ip

I'm working on a API project that depends partialy from $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] (like 50%).

My API checks the IP of client first and then checks the token, and i want to know if should i worry about getting this IP from this global variable.

can the client some how "forge" this?

i know that VPN can camouflage the IP, but thats not a problem since he will not getting access anyway.

Comment: Yes .. TBH there is no **100%** reliable way to determine someone's IP address.  If they come in via VPN .. It's not accurate.  If they [Spoof](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55279/how-easy-is-it-really-to-do-ip-spoofing)  Again . Not accurate.  However, as of 2019, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the *best* way to determine the clients IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the three way handshake of TCP/IP - `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` cannot be spoofed. There is (however) no guarantee that this is the IP address of the end user. He may be behind proxy or VPN. What you can guarantee with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is that the machine which is directly connected to you has this exact IP and it is real.

Comment: As @Philip Petrov stated, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is *reliable*  --  In no way should it be considered **secure** ...  It is impossible to grab someone's IP address via PHP if their **intent** is to hide their IP address.

Comment: Im not looking for get the real ip address, i just want to get the real IP of connection to certificate if the token user has the same ip. If has a VPN, the ip will be different, so will not authenticate anyway.
i have this question when i was testing python and in a DDOS example from a youtube video has a fake_ip variable:
`socket.sendto (("Host:" + fake_ip + "\ r \ n \ r \ n"). encode ('ascii'), (target, port))`
and its not a fake ip of target ...

Comment: YOUR code could be behind a load balancer or reverse proxy as well... you should also check the X-headers in the SERVER array (proxy will set the original IP to a X-header and it's own IP into REMOTE_ADDR)